# Save logged on user(name only) in ORACLE when OS based authentication is used

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

em new to oracle and wanted to know that how can i save the username in table  from which he is logged on, when i use OS based authentication in oracle....
any guide would be helpful

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the name of OS user name (like logged user in windows for example) write the following:

```
select  sys_context('USERENV','OS_USER')  from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

next query will return to you the name of the user that is logged in:

```
select user from dual
```

Now, all you need is to use "user" as a value in your insert statement.